# When I type on path, my shape fill is gone. How do I fill my shape after I type on path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shapes

[image: So here is where I draw and fill my circle.]

[image: Here is where I type on path and my circle fill is gone.]

How do I fill my circle and still keep my type on path message?

Comment: Hey thyn75! Just wanted to welcome you to GD.SE! If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I actually always find it better to copy the path first, then apply the types on a path, Then paste in front/back if I need to original shape again. I don't apply type on a path to filled shapes or stroked paths. Maybe I'm just old-school :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) to select the path.

You can see if you use the normal Selection Tool (black arrow), the top bar will show you have "Type" selected and the color of your type will show in the color panel:

[image]

Selecting the path itself with the Direct Selection Tool will show you have selected an "Anchor Point" (or "Path" if you select the whole path, but with no fill you need to select every anchor point to do that) and the fill and stroke color will show as none:

[image]

Set your fill and stroke as you wish:

[image]